# Displaying alphabetical phone number (in numbers) with multiple methods

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

How can i get this program to actually run? Every time I put in the main method it messes up everything up, but I know I'm supposed to include it. I'm supposed to input a phone number with words ex 1-800-FLOWERS and its supposed to print 1-800-3569377. Im supposed to use these specific methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Translator
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    char character;
    String input, inputTwo, phoneNumber;
public void getInput()
{
    System.out.println("Enter the alphabetic phone number.");
    input = kb.next();
    inputTwo = input.toLowerCase();
    isValid(inputTwo);
}
public void isValid(String numb)
{
    inputTwo = numb;
    int error = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < inputTwo.length(); i++)
    {
        character = inputTwo.charAt(i);
        switch(character)
        {
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case 'a':
            case 'b':
            case 'c':
            case '2':
            case 'd':
            case 'e':
            case 'f':
            case '3':
            case 'g':
            case 'h':
            case 'i':
            case '4':
            case 'j':
            case 'k':
            case 'l':
            case '5':
            case 'm':
            case 'n':
            case 'o':
            case '6':
            case 'p':
            case 'q':
            case 'r':
            case 's':
            case '7':
            case 't':
            case 'u':
            case 'v':
            case '8':
            case 'w':
            case 'x':
            case 'y':
            case 'z':
            case '9':
            case '_':
                break;
            default:
                error ++;
        }
    }
    int trueError = error;
    if((inputTwo.length() >= 10 && inputTwo.length() <= 14) && trueError == 0)
    {
        getPhoneNumber(inputTwo);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("you did not enter a vaild phone number. Try again.");
}
public String getPhoneNumber(String numbTwo)
{
    inputTwo = numbTwo;
    for(int i = 0; i < numbTwo.length(); i++)
    {
        character = inputTwo.charAt(i);
        switch(character)
        {
            case '0':
                phoneNumber += 0;
                break;
            case '1':
                phoneNumber += 1;
                break;
            case 'a':
            case 'b':
            case 'c':
            case '2':
                phoneNumber += 2;
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'e':
            case 'f':
            case '3':
                phoneNumber += 3;
                break;
            case 'g':
            case 'h':
            case 'i':
            case '4':
                phoneNumber += 4;
                break;
            case 'j':
            case 'k':
            case 'l':
            case '5':
                phoneNumber += 5;
                break;
            case 'm':
            case 'n':
            case 'o':
            case '6':
                phoneNumber += 6;
                break;
            case 'p':
            case 'q':
            case 'r':
            case 's':
            case '7':
                phoneNumber += 7;
                break;
            case 't':
            case 'u':
            case 'v':
            case '8':
                phoneNumber += 8;
                break;
            case 'w':
            case 'x':
            case 'y':
            case 'z':
            case '9':
                phoneNumber += 9;
                break;
            default:
                phoneNumber += '_';
        }
    }
    System.out.println(phoneNumber);
}
}
```

Comment: *it messes up everything up, but I know I'm supposed to include it.* -- Please be more specific, what exactly is getting messed up?

Answer (score 0):

So to run this, it seems you would need to create a main function, then create the Translator class to run the internal functions. Add the following code inside of
the Translator class file and then run it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Translator translator = new Translator();
    translator.getInput();
}
```

Then just enter whatever alphabetic number, and it should work. 
The reason I create a translator class in the main function is because if you call the method names directly in the main function, you will have to make all of those public methods to be static. Doing it this way allows you to leave it unchanged.